# Where is Gradle autocomplete in IDEA?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, autocomplete

I am using Gradle 2.3 inside of IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE and Android Studio 1.3.2 and have always wondered what the situation is with gradle autocomplete / syntax highlighting etc.

When I look at a build.gradle file most of the code is dark gray and underlined, even keywords like `task` giving `Cannot resolve symbol 'task'`.

[image]

Coming from using Java in IDEA I find it disorientating and I would expect that types (like `Javadoc`) would be click through-able and auto-complete would offer me relevant stuff (like the methods and properties of `Javadoc` when inside the above `task`).

It would also be great if I could enumerate the source sets for this build file via autocomplete at the `sourceSets.`, which I appreciate may need gradle to have executed the config build step to provide this info.

Am I missing something obvious or is Gradle tooling inside IDEA just not as good as the Java equivalents?

Thanks!

Comment: I hope you don't do this for all questions involving IntelliJ :/

Answer (score 1):

It could be **Cucumber for Groovy** plugin. As I know Gradle use some techniques and syntax of Groovy, so I tried to install some Groovy plugins and success at the first try.

[image]

Steps to install this plug in:

- on MacOS: **Preferences... -> Install JetBrains plugin... -> Cucumber
  for Groovy**.

[image]

Comment: Do you know of an equivalent plugin for Android Studio?

Comment: It's a plugin for Android Studio @Kyle

Comment: Not the latest versions.
`Plugin 'Cucumber for Groovy' is compatible with IntelliJ IDEA only because it doesn't define any explicit module dependencie`

Comment: oh I have no idea now :)